# Media files in Django

Tags: django, django-models, media, django-urls, django-staticfiles

I think I'm doing everything correctly but the images won't show on the website although they get added successfully in the media folder...

media/product_images

inside media is the placeholder image + product_images folder

Model Field

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_images/', default='placeholder.png')
```

Settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static'
]

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

Urls

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the html file you used to display images on the website.

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT should be declared as ```MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/media'```

Comment: I had to  delete all the images i had in the folder and upload them again and now its working